# How to add some text at the bottom of navigation in SharePoint 2013

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to add some text just below the navigation menu in SharePoint 2013. I created a .aspx page trying to do just that. However, my text is always appearing above the navigation rather than below it.

Here is my code piece in the default.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderLeftActions" runat="server">
    PlaceHolderLeftActions PlaceHolderLeftActionsPlaceHolderLeftActionsPlaceHolderLeftActionsPlaceHol
</asp:Content>
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

The placeholder text is supposed to be after the navigation; any idea how to do that?

Comment: Can you include the code that creates the navigation view as well? On the surface, the obvious solution is to move your custom code to below the navigation code.

Comment: I ended up creating  a custom user control and added that control just below the navigation in the master page it self.